# Use jquery to make div appear after a user scrolls

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, appearance

I'd like to have a div appear after a user scrolls down on a page, and disappears if they scroll back to the top.

I thought using the .scroll() function in jquery would be useful, but couldn't quite figure out how to make this happen.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
        $("#mydiv:visible").hide();
    }
    else {
        $("#mydiv:hidden").show();
    }
});
```