# Floating footer to only appear once user has scrolled down 200px

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, sticky-footer

I'm building a site which requires a Footer which will float at the bottom of the browser window at all times.

However, this should only appear once the user has scrolled down 200px. It should then scroll in place (as if the footer is attached to the content 200px out of view, but attaches itself to the browser window).

As soon as the user scrolls back up, this needs to then be hidden again.

How can this be done?

Comment: Doesn't the tutorial you linked to show how to achieve this?

Comment: sorry for the dumb comment maybe I don't understand well but are you sure it doesn't do what you need already? See here: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html In presence of a long page content It seems to do what you need. Am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I've explained myself well. It needs to float on top of the content, so its always fixed to the bottom of the browser window

Comment: Edited content, I hope this explains a bit better

Comment: ...I mean just use/resize that long page to see a CSS footer behavior similar to what you seems to need.

Comment: The footer always needs to be visible on the page at all times, once the scoll is 200px down

Comment: maybe a customized version of this http://css-tricks.com/examples/jQueryStickyFooter/

Comment: You can have a look here for the right answer:

[Use jquery to make div appear after a user scrolls (SO Question)][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573767/use-jquery-to-make-div-appear-after-a-user-scrolls

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe this piece of code can help you out:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 200) {
        $("#footer").hide();
    }
    else {
        $("#footer").show();
    }
});
```

and for the CSS add

```
#footer {
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    display:none;
}
```

Something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() < 200) {
    $("footer").slideUp();
      }
  else {
    $("footer").slideDown();
      }
});
```

Comment: Cheers @DKSan, This is the sort of thing I'm after! Is there anyway I can get this to scroll into position rather than hide/show? So as you scroll down the page it appears from the bottom, and then gets fixed onto the browser window as you navigate further down the page?

Comment: Yes, but to make it html4 just alter the doctype, change `<footer>` to `<div class="footer">` and change css rule `footer` to `#footer`. Same for article

Comment: As you scroll down, the footer gets animated.  Even if you scroll down very very slowly, the footer is animated at the same speed.  Is this the desired effect?

Answer (score 1):

I think http://jsfiddle.net/KEjfe/4/ is what you want, from what I gather in your question.

**BUT**

I want to you to know that the fiddle is a crude example and I had to hack to together because it was in fiddle.  But the idea is there, which is that you make 2 of the same footers.  One that is in a fixed position (in the fiddle it's absolute), and one that is in a absolute position (in the fiddle it's relative).  Then you can have the same type of `if` statement in my fiddle, once you scroll past 200px from the top, remove the absolute positioned and show the fixed, and vice versa when you are below 200px.

So remember:

- A div that is fixed positioned (which is the sticky footer)
- A div that is absolute positioned (which is the flowing footer)

Comment: Cheers @vinceh. Why is there a horizontal scrollbar half way down the result window? I can't work it out :S

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need [fixed footer](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fixed-footer/).